# How best to get rid of household stuff?

Tags: storage

I'm moving across half of the country to take a new job and I have a storage unit full of household and miscellaneous stuff. Was planning to move everything to the new place but the moving companies' estimates are way higher than what the stuffs are worth for. So am now thinking maybe just move some key pieces of furniture and get rid of everything else (kitchen stuff, plates, etc.). Don't have time for yard sale (no yard anyway). What's the best way to dispose of the unwanted household and miscellaneous stuff? Thanks!

Comment: "Halfway across the country" could mean anything from a few km to 5000 km… you may want to clarify.

Comment: It's across several states.

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way to dispose of the unwanted household and miscellaneous stuff?

- Sell whatever is worth selling.
- Check if there are charity stores in your area.  They may pick up usable household and miscellaneous stuff, perhaps even for free.    If you have access to a car or a (large) freight bike, you can bring things yourself.
- Post on your local/regional "classified ads" website advertising that people can pick up miscellaneous stuff for free.
- Put a big box of stuff outside your home with a note that people can take things for free.
- Whatever remains, you can either bring (even if it's economically not worth it) or recycle.

Answer (score 1):

### Reuse > recycle > discard

Put up on Craigslist and Freecycle to see if anyone wants it. Facebook Marketplace is also a popular place now.

Take what you can to Goodwill/Salvation Army, though honestly, this can be a burden to them if it's not saleable or if it's stuff they have a glut of. The fact is, America is just swimming in "stuff" - we have more of it than we know what to do with.  As a rule, people buy new for everything, so what good is used stuff?

*Familiarize yourself with your local recycling rules and do not throw anything in a recycle bin that is not on the list*. Starting right now, **never miss an opportunity to absolutely fill your recycle bins**.  In fact if a nearby town has drive-up recycling (where you can throw legal recylables in a public bin) take full advantage of that.

When the above is exhausted, never miss an opportunity to fill a trash bin that you have a right to fill. Trash costs *somebody* money to dispose of: Do not steal bin space.

Finally talk to the storage site operator about options - this happens all the time, they know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about moving out of an apartment of house. If you are in the United States, then take the items you do not want to the ARC Thrift Store or to Good Will.